# EPUB3 audio button too big

Tags: html, audio, epub3

I'm building an EPUB3 ibook and want to incorporate audio.
I'm succeeding, in so far as that I have a screen on my iPad2 with a button to play the audio file.
But that button is ugly and way too big. I suppose it's some default button of Apple.
How can I influence the way the button looks?

The XHTML tag I use now is like this:

`<audio controls="controls" src="dir1/sound.wav">sound.wav not present</audio>`

That's all I do now. Nothing epub:type for this whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Apple has royally failed on the audio player in this last iOS update... But the good thing is: you can build your own using Javascript!

You can find most of the main functions here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp.

As long as the audio container is in the same chapter, you should be able to control it with the functions above (just hide it and don't show controls). Then you can use custom CSS to build your player from scratch (cool example here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-customized-html5-audio-player--webdesign-7081)!

You should also use .mp3 format for best file sizes and results...

Good luck!